# Prove that $7^{\frac 14}$ is not rational using the Unique Factorization Theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, prime-factorization

I am currently trying to prove this using the Unique Factorization Theorem and I am stuck.

I attempt to prove this BWOC and assume $7^{\frac 14}$ is rational so that it can be expressed as $\frac ab$.

Thus $7 = \frac {a^4}{b^4} \implies 7b^4 = a^4$.
If both  $a^4$ and $b^4$ have unique prime factorizations, how do I get there to conclude that $7^{\frac 14}$ is irrational?

Comment: Hint:  $7$ must divide $a$, whence $7^4$ divides $a^4$.

Comment: The highest power of $7$ that divides $a^4$ is $4s$ for some $s$. The highest power of $7$ that divides $7b^4$ is $4t+1$ for some $t$.  Hence we cannot have $a^4=7b^4$.

Comment: As @AndréNicolas says, you have different numbers of $7$’s on the two sides of the equation $7b^4=a^4$: divisible by $4$ on the right, not so on the left.

Comment: @lulu: You missed the $a^4,b^4$ in your edit.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo  Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the proof that $2^{1/2}$ is irrational?  This one will go pretty much the same way.

Comment: 7 is prime so if 7 divides$a^4$ then 7|a, so $7^4|a^4$ so $7^3|b^4$ so $7|b^4$ so $7|b$ so $7$ divides both $a$ and $b$, so $a$ and $b$ were not chosen to be relatively prime.  This the value can not be expressed as a ratio of relatively prime integers.  Thus not rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can assume that $\text{gcd}(a,b) = 1$. Using UFT for $a,b$ you can argue that $a = 7^{x_1}\cdots a_n^{x_n}, b = 7^{y_1}\cdots b_n^{y_n}$. Thus $\text{gcd}(a,b) > 1$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Suppose that $a= 7^{\frac 1 4}$ is rational.

Then, $a^4=7$, so $a$ is a root of $X^4-7$. But the rational root theorem says it's not.